# Table java. Without arrays

Tags: java

Can I get some help with this code? I don't know where my mistake is, probably in the second for. I need this data to be printed as a table, but I have the last name printed 3 times. Where am I wrong?

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class BMI {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        String first_name = null;
        int kg = 0 ;
        double height = 0;
        double bmi = 0;
    
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        System.out.print("NAME ");
        first_name=scanner.next();
        System.out.print("WEIGHT, kg");
        kg=scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("HEIGHT, m");
        height=scanner.nextDouble();
        bmi= kg / (height * height);
    
        }
         
        System.out.printf("%s %20s %20s %20s", "NAME", "Weight", "Height", "BMI");
        System.out.println();
        
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%-10s %12d %21.2f %22.2f",first_name,kg,height,bmi);
        System.out.println();
        
        }
        
    } 

}
```

Comment: right now you just have one variable for each attributes which prints its last assigned value. Given you have more than one, you need to use a collection (Arraylist of an object which has name, weight and height as instance variables)

Comment: You are using a `for` loop to get the name, weight and height 3 times, and using another `for` loop to print them 3 times. I'm pretty sure that's not what you want? Or are you trying to calculate BMI for 3 people?

Comment: You have a wallet. You take out the wallet, throw away everything inside, and put a 1 dollar bill into it. You do that 3 times. Why would you expect to find 3 bills in there? If you want to store **three different** values, then you either need 3 different variables (bad idea), or you have to use an array, or a list, ...

Comment: An additional problem is that the `Scanner` methods you are using do not consume end of line characters, so unless you call `nextLine()` after each one your weight and height variables will not have the values you expect. See [this](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/4Tq) for an implementation that solves both issues (though it can be improved by using arrays or collections, but I leave that as an exercise for you).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, each calculation in the first for loop overwrites the values of the previous calculation.
Thus, only the values of the last calculation are then printed out.
You need to store the 3 different data blocks in separate places, e.g. using Arrays:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BMI {

    public static final int ENTRIES = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] first_name = new String[ENTRIES];
        int[] kg = new int[ENTRIES];
        double[] height = new double[ENTRIES];
        double[] bmi = new double[ENTRIES];

        for(int i = 0; i < ENTRIES; i++) {
            System.out.print("NAME ");
            first_name[i] = scanner.next();
            System.out.print("WEIGHT, kg");
            kg[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("HEIGHT, m");
            height[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
            bmi[i] = kg[i] / (height[i] * height[i]);
        }
     
        System.out.printf("%s %20s %20s %20s", "NAME", "Weight", "Height", "BMI");
        System.out.println();
    
        for(int i = 0; i < ENTRIES; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%-10s %12d %21.2f %22.2f",first_name[i],kg[i],height[i],bmi[i]);
            System.out.println();
    
        }
    } 

}
```

As you might have noticed, I also used a constant to define the number of entries used in a single place.

Comment: When giving code, make sure it is properly formatted. Also note the repetition of the literal "3". If you want to change this to 5 values, you have to change 6 different lines of codes. Thus it would be MUCH better to use a constant for that value!

Comment: Indeed, it definitely is. I left it out because it wasn't within the scope of the asked question, but I now updated it :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are actually printing information of 3 person. So you actually would need variables to maintain information for 3 persons. While your current code has one variable for each property. That's why your final iteration of first loop override everything. So you should use 3 different variables:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMI {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    final List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

      final Person person = new Person();
      System.out.print("NAME ");
      person.first_name = scanner.next();
      System.out.print("WEIGHT, kg");
      person.kg = scanner.nextInt();
      System.out.print("HEIGHT, m");
      person.height = scanner.nextDouble();
      person.bmi = person.kg / (person.height * person.height);

      persons.add(person);

    }

    System.out.printf("%s %20s %20s %20s", "NAME", "Weight", "Height", "BMI");
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      System.out.printf("%-10s %12d %21.2f %22.2f", persons.get(i).first_name, persons.get(i).kg, persons.get(i).height,
          persons.get(i).bmi);
      System.out.println();

    }

  }
}

class Person {

  double bmi = 0;

  String first_name = null;

  double height = 0;

  int kg = 0;
}
```

This code can be improved in many ways, but for your understanding keeping it in sync with your code.